# Cannot get the Context when using AppCompatAcitvity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass the `Context` to my `ListViewAdapter` class using:

```
    private ContactAdapter adapter = new ContactAdapter(this);
```

But I'm getting a null pointer in my `ContactAdapter` class, it cannot find the `Context`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Logcat:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at info.androidhive.materialnavbar.ContactAdapter.readTextFileAsList(ContactAdapter.java:67)
        at info.androidhive.materialnavbar.ContactAdapter.<init>(ContactAdapter.java:30)
        at info.androidhive.materialnavbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
```

Method inside `Adapter` using the context:

```
    public List<Contact> readTextFileAsList(Context ctx, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    List<Contact> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try
    {
        while (( line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] a = line.split(";");
            list.add(new Contact(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]));
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return list;
}
```

When the adapter get's initialized:

underneath the constructor

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;

public ContactAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

private List<Contact> codeLearnChapterList = readTextFileAsList(ctx, R.raw.testcrawljs);
```

Comment: Where is your logcat???

Answer (score 3):

Do not use an `Activity` in an initializer, as the activity is not ready yet. Change:

```
private ContactAdapter adapter = new ContactAdapter(this);
```

to:

```
private ContactAdapter adapter;
```

And add:

```
adapter = new ContactAdapter(this);
```

to your `onCreate()` method, somewhere after `super.onCreate()`.

---

**UPDATE**

```
private List<Contact> codeLearnChapterList = readTextFileAsList(ctx, R.raw.testcrawljs);
```

`ctx` is `null` here, because you have not assigned a value to it yet. Move the `readTextFileAsList()` call into the constructor.

Comment: I see but the context will still be null

Comment: @Lozeputten: Then perhaps you should edit the question to show your implementation of `readTextFileAsList()`, as that is where your problem lies.

Comment: i've added the method

Comment: @Lozeputten: Now, please show where you are calling `readTextFileAsList()`, from the `ContactsAdapter` constructor. Note that you should not be doing disk I/O on the main application thread, and so all of this code needs to be rewritten at some point, if you want to have a smoothly-running app. Also, please show `MainActivity` `onCreate()`, at least through the line where you invoke the `ContactsAdapter` constructor.

Comment: i've added the Constructor and the initialized list

Comment: I've done that, but im keeping a null pointer for some reason, now it shows the null pointer on the list.